# Socket.io nodejs cluster hash loadbalancing with proxy

Tags: websocket, socket.io, load-balancing, haproxy, pm2

I built an app where people connect to rooms through websocket based on the room's id in the URL, such as app.com/9l4CvjXFxn . The thing is I want to run multiple node instances in order to secure an always up instance, in case others crash, and also because I heard loadbalancing is good. I also have the static UI content to serve. I am using socketio only, no REST api.

My plan now is to use a load-balancing and serving proxy such as nginx or haproxy. I have never used any of them. I have also thought about using PM2 to easily run many node instances. The app will probably be deployed on AWS.

Websockets happen through an HTTP1 upgrade to a certain path in socketio, I have set it to root /. So in the initial upgrade request I can't change the path, but I can put things into the url query or cookie headers.

So the main requirement for the loadbalancer is to direct websocket upgrades of a certain room to one specific node instance consistently, hence I thought of hash loadbalancing, but I have no idea how to do this and if this is the correct approach at all. 
Could you help?
Thanks!

Comment: Some OP deleted my thumbs up emojies :( Who was that almighty OP?

Comment: Comeforth and help instead :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't solve it and it might be that its a "wrong" problem to have. This is because I don't have persistence and I keep my objects in node. If my node instance was stateless and use a redis I could spin up many nodes without having this problem. This is the next step though because, still an early app. Checkiout though: quarantime.io :)